# How to disable type 1 when i click on Type 2 in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I click on Type 2 but still the values which i select in type 2 is getting displayed in both type 1 and type 2 in frontend. How to avoid this?

I tried ng disabled = type 1 but still i get my values displayed in type 1

Comment: Please provide more information with some code snippet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.